# Redis / Homestead / Laravel 7 - Connection Refused

Tags: php, laravel, testing, redis, homestead

I am trying to get Redis working whilst following the Let's build a forum with TDD series. I have got to Episode 66 which introduces Redis and written the first test...and then boom, it blows up. Have done a lot of googling around but the answers do not seem to correlate.

I am using homestead and thus redis should be installed in the environment - using a Vagrant box on Windows.

I have installed predis and confirm this is pulling in via the vendor library and compose package

I have SSH'd into the homestead box and run redis-cli and performed ping /pong test to confirm that the redis server is infact running.

I have also run a redis-server --version version test.

```
Redis server v=5.0.8 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=129cf1a0751f12a
```

Following the tutorial I have written the first test

```
public function test_it_increments_a_threads_score_each_time_it_is_read()
    {

        $this->assertEmpty( Redis::zrevrange('trending_threads', 0, -1));

        $thread = create('App\Thread');

        $this->call('GET', $thread->path());

        Redis::zrevrange('trending_threads', 0, -1);

        $this->assertCount(1,  Redis::zrevrange('trending_threads', 0, -1));


    }
```

and all I get is

```
Predis\Connection\ConnectionException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

I am really struggling to work out why/how this message is persisting when I have followed everything line by line, I am not using Xamp or anything other than Homestead yet still getting this error.

The config is the standard config, updated to the predis library

```
    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

My Homestead Yaml

```
---
ip: "10.100.110.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:

    - map: tweety.test.com
      to: /home/vagrant/code/tweety/public

    - map: bird.test.com
      to: /home/vagrant/code/birdboard/public

    - map: ecosystem.test.com
      to: /home/vagrant/code/ecosystem/public

    - map: multiform.test.com
      to: /home/vagrant/code/multi_upload/public


databases:
    - tweety
    - birdboard
    - ecosystem
    - multi_upload

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Has anybody come across this before or have any idea on direction? It is driving me bonkers and is quite a big blocker in the series.

For reference - I am running Laravel 7 on Homestead via a Vagrant Box on my windows laptop. :)

Cheers all

Comment: There's a very very small chance changing localhost to 127.0.01 (or vice-versa since I see both here) might work. If not then try to change the redis configuration to change the bind host to `0.0.0.0` to allow connections from everywhere. Normally this should not be necessary if redis is running on the same "machine" (real or virtual) as the webserver but it might be worth trying out

Answer (score 0):

could you add also your Homestead.yaml file?
It could be that you need to change the ip address in this file to 192.168.10.10

Comment: I have updated with the YAML. Thanks for taking a look. :) ... The IP here is connected to my Hosts file to allows me to run localhost via test URLs.

Comment: @AdamCatlow 10.100.110.10 is used to map between your windows to vagrant. I'm guessing your redis is not on vagrant - maybe try to set its ip location to the one you configured (10.100.110.10). right now you get access denied because you are trying to connect to your localhost machine with 6379 port

Comment: Thanks - yes, it was related to that IP. What I have resorted to doing, not sure if the correct way, but just adding it here incase anyone else runs into same issue, is basically go into the redis.conf file within the Virtual Homestead box and change the binding from 127.0.0.1 to 10.100.110.10. 

I then restarted the redis-server and updated the .env REDIS_HOST with the new value. This seems to have solved the issue.

In short - make sure the IP in the Hosts file matches the IP in the Redis Config - if you have changed it from the defaults. Default values should be fine. IE localhosts.